# React JS Constructor vs useState what's the difference?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between constructor and useState, I tried them both and they work on same solution.

`UseState`

```
  const [filterName, setFilterName] = useState("");
  const [robots, setRobots] = useState([]);
```

vs

`constructor`

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      robots: robots,
      searchfield: ""
    }
  }
```

Comment: The constructor is used in class components annd useState is used in function components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, these are two different approaches in React. The **constructor** type is part of the OOP React approach with the so called **class components**. There you have class methods instead of functions. And the state is accessed through `this.state.<property>`.

The other approach is the **function components**. That's the more modern way of doing stuff with React. `useState()` is a React hook, responsible for a particular state.

They work the same, however the function-based approach is getting more and more common, so I would suggest to switch to function components, unless something requires the explicit usage of class components.